# How to export files with different frame rates in a composition in premiere pro?

Tags: premiere, adobe-media-encoder

I have game play videos with frames of 59.94 fps, 60 fps, and some around 30 fps. I put all these files in one sequence. When trying to export, the file created is unplayable. Can anyone help me out with my issue.

**Note:** I am using premiere pro cs6

Comment: You need to provide more information. What filetype are your recordings? Are they playable in premiere? Which export-settings did you use? What are the settings of your sequence? With which program did you try to open the rendered file? I'm sorry if that's a pain in the rear, but without further elaboration, we'd be virtually left to guessing...

Comment: The file exported will be in MP4 format. Files inside are also mp4 format. But I converted two files from 59.38 fps to 59.94 fps and then added them to the sequence in order to keep the framerate of the sequence same. Not sure why it is exporting a corrupted file

Comment: When you're saying you converted the 59.38 file to 59.94 - where did you get the 59.38 fps file from? That's a usual framerate, so the issue might be there. You wouldn't have to convert the file anyways as far as I am concerned, since you will bring the file to a universal framerate anyways. Another question: Did you use the h264 codec for your mp4?

Comment: typo: I obviously meant "that's NOT a usual framerate"